# hide the localhost path name XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

Hello There Im Looking For Efficient Way To Hide The Path File In XAMPP LOCALHOST

For Example The Default Path Is [ For Wordpress Files ]

```
localhost/wordpress
```

how can i turn it to

```
localhost only without the /wordpress file path ?
```

i tired to add a dns localhost to ==>

**host file in**

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

like

```
127.0.0.1            testing.com
```

and added this to the httpd-vhosts.conf

default port is == 80

```
<VirtualHost *:8010> 
  DocumentRoot "F:\DEV\htdocs\wordpress" 
  ServerName testing.com
  ServerAlias testing.com
     <Directory "F:\DEV\htdocs\wordpress> 
        Require all granted 
     </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

when i enter == testing.com  [ it's redirecting me to testing.com/dashboard  -- testing.com/wordpress

i just need it testing.com

I USE

**XAMPP Control Panel V3.2.4**

**Apache Server**

**MySQL Database**

**Wordpress framework == 5.5.1**

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code it might help you.

Add this line **In host file**
127.0.0.1    testing.com

I have just tested this code and it's working

This code in **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  ## i have removed 10 from port and it was working in mine
  DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress" 
  ServerName testing.com
  ServerAlias testing.com
     <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress> 
        Require all granted 
     </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```